# document is null when running Jest test with Create React App

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm running a Jest test, which is erroring out when I set state due to react-dom not finding document.  I put a log statement in react-dom and I see that document is populated initially

```
  console.log node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5066
    !!!! Document {
      location: [Getter/Setter],
      _reactListenersID0002526682692260973: 0 }
```

but later in the test execution it's null and that's the error I encounter in my Jest test.

```
  console.log node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5066
    !!!! null
```

Error Message:

```
  console.log src/containers/App.js:266
    handleError TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
        at getActiveElement (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5069:16)
        at getActiveElementDeep (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5334:17)
        at getSelectionInformation (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5366:21)
        at prepareForCommit (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8689:26)
        at commitRoot (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17711:3)
        at completeRoot (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19239:3)
        at performWorkOnRoot (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19168:9)
        at performWork (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19076:7)
        at performSyncWork (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19050:3)
        at requestWork (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18919:5)
        at scheduleWork (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18728:5)
        at Object.enqueueSetState (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12456:5)
        at App.Object.<anonymous>.Component.setState (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:375:16)
        at setState (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/src/containers/App.js:250:14)
        at tryCatcher (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
        at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
        at _drainQueueStep (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
        at _drainQueue (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
        at Async.Object.<anonymous>.Async._drainQueues (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/jc/projects/grip/grip-client/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
        at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
        at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

import configureStore from '../../store/configureStore';

global.Promise = require('bluebird');
const util = require('util');

jest.mock('../../actions/simulationRuns');
let App;

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Set up some mocked out file info before each test
    App = require('../App').default;
  });

  it('renders without crashing - mount', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router>
        <Provider store={configureStore()}>
          <Route path="/">
            <App />
          </Route>
        </Provider>
      </Router>,
      div
    );
  });
});
```

setupTests.js

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Comment: Why are you using ReactDOM.render in test files. That is something mount or shallow. based on unit requierments what you use, will do it for you. I will suggest you to have a look at the unit test docs before

Comment: @Mohit Tilwani, In the Create React App testing page, it shows using  ReactDOM.render in the Testing Components example: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests

Comment: I've seen a similar problem with vue/test-utils and resolved it. The cause of the problem is that some promises are resolved after finishing tests and promises causes re-render. Jest has finished a cleanup and document became null. So I write code to wait for all promises. Maybe re-render causes after cleanup in this code.